# componentWillMount() is there any option to use it in 0.63?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wanted to get data from the Database before the actual Screen is rendert. but the componentWillMount function isn't usable anymore. How can I do it now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getDerivedStateFromProps()` or `useLayoutEffect()`, but do you really need it before the initial render? If you fetch your data in eg. `componentDidMount()` (the most common way) and use `setState()` inside, the component will re-render and you'd get your fetched data rendered...

Comment: how can i use this function in a functional component ? i get an error : expectet ;

Comment: Use the `useLayoutEffect` hook

Answer (score -1):

You can use UNSAFE_componentWillMount with a class component.  It should work through React v17.

Comment: and how can i do it in functional component?

Comment: useEffect or useLayoutEffect